# What's the meaning of "what's the draw"?

Tags: meaning

I watched the TV serials *How I Met Your Mother*. And the phrase came out when Robin said,

***"What? I mean, I don't hate kids.***

***I'm-I'm just not a kid person.***

***I mean, yeah, it's cute that their shoes are real little, but beyond that, what's the draw?***

***You must think I'm nuts."***

I've google the phrase but the best result I had it's this yahoo answer: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110721200654AALrS17, which I don't think quite fit in here.

Comment: [Draw](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw): something or someone that attracts people.

Comment: Since no one has pointed it out specifically yet: there's a big difference between your titular "*what's draw"* and the actual quote "*what's **the** draw*". The second is correct and common, as deadrat explained; the former, the title of this question, is ungrammatical and senseless.

Comment: @DanBron My mistake. Have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One meaning of the word "draw" is to pull in various *directions*, as in a horse-drawn carriage, i.e, one *pulled* *along* by a horse.  Or consider that a [chimney sweep](https://chimneysweeponline.com/hodraft.htm) will tell you that

> Chimneys often **draw** at least a small amount of air, even when
>   there is no fire below....

That is, a chimney will *pull up* air from the fireplace room and out of the house even when there's no fire lit.

In a figurative sense, if the meaning is *pull towards*, then the person feeling the force of the pull will feel an attraction.  Thus from Terry Brooks' [*The Elf Queen of Shannara*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dvX3cAAsA4cC&pg=PA273&dq=%22the%20draw%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgUahUKEwiS2eyK6qLHAhVLFz4KHdLiAIk#v=onepage&q=%22the%20draw%20of%22&f=false):

> She could feel the **draw** of two choices, very different, each
>   compelling.

Two choices, each with its own attraction.  And that's the meaning of the sitcom line, "What's the draw?" namely, "What's the attraction of having children around?"